# Xml, C#, XmlNodeList do not get selected nodes

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xpath, xmlnodelist

I'm new in programming and do not understand, why this code:

```
XmlNodeList elemPrice = doc.SelectNodes(
    "//Items/Item/Offers/Offer/OfferListing/Price/FormattedPrice");
```

don't give selected nodes. I watched the xml doc for getting xpath and it is right.

It gives null in searchedItem.Price line, when tried to execute this:

```
List <SearchedItem> searchedItems = new List<SearchedItem>();

for (int i = 0; i < elemAsin.Count; i++)
{
    SearchedItem searchedItem = new SearchedItem();
    searchedItem.Asin = elemAsin[i].InnerText;
    searchedItem.CurrencyCode = elemCurrencyCode[i].InnerText;
    string price = elemPrice[i].InnerText.Remove(0, 1);
    searchedItem.Price = double.Parse(price);
    searchedItems.Add(searchedItem);
}

return searchedItems;
```

Comment: Please post your xml

Comment: *"I watched the xml doc for getting xpath and it is right"*.  It it was right, it would be working.  You need to include the XML, as it stands no one can give you an answer.

Comment: You probably have a namespace in the xml that is causing issue.

Comment: In order for us to help you, we need to see a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello!  I make the request and get the response: WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

            if (webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {

                doc.Load(webResponse.GetResponseStream()); The amazon xml response

Comment: The amazon xml response

<ItemSearchResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">

<Items>

<Item>

<ASIN>B00OTWOAAQ</ASIN>

<Offers>

<Offer>

<OfferListing>

<Price>

<FormattedPrice>$374.33</FormattedPrice>

</Price>

</OfferListing>

</Offer>

</Offers>

</Item>

</Items>

</ItemSearchResponse>

Comment: The amazon response give only 10 item search. How do I get 13? Any help would be thankful:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found other method to parse XML, which is fine and easy.

```
 public static List<SearchedItem> ItemSearchResponse(string url)
    {
        List<SearchedItem> searchedItems = new List<SearchedItem>();

        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());

        doc.LoadXml(reader.ReadToEnd());

        XmlNodeList listIsValid = doc.GetElementsByTagName("IsValid");

        if (listIsValid.Count > 0 && listIsValid[0].InnerXml == "True")
        {
            XmlNodeList listItems = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Item");

            foreach (XmlNode nodeItem in listItems)
            {
                SearchedItem searchedItem = new SearchedItem();

                foreach (XmlNode nodeChild in nodeItem.ChildNodes)
                {
                    if (nodeChild.Name == "DetailPageURL")
                    {
                        searchedItem.DetailPageURL = nodeChild.InnerText;
                    }

                    else if (nodeChild.Name == "SmallImage")
                    {
                        foreach (XmlNode nodeURLImg in nodeChild.ChildNodes)
                        {
                            if (nodeURLImg.Name == "URL")
                            {
                                searchedItem.SmallImage = nodeURLImg.InnerText;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    else if (nodeChild.Name == "ItemAttributes")
                    {
                        foreach (XmlNode nodeItemAtributes in nodeChild.ChildNodes)
                        {
                            if (nodeItemAtributes.Name == "Title")
                            {
                                searchedItem.Title = nodeItemAtributes.InnerText;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    else if (nodeChild.Name == "OfferSummary")
                    {
                        foreach (XmlNode nodeOfferSummary in nodeChild.ChildNodes)
                        {
                            if (nodeOfferSummary.Name == "LowestNewPrice")
                            {
                                foreach (XmlNode nodeLowestNewPrice in nodeOfferSummary.ChildNodes)
                                {
                                    if (nodeLowestNewPrice.Name == "CurrencyCode")
                                    {
                                        searchedItem.CurrencyCode = nodeLowestNewPrice.InnerText;
                                    }

                                    else if (nodeLowestNewPrice.Name == "FormattedPrice")
                                    {
                                        string price = nodeLowestNewPrice.InnerText.Remove(0, 1);
                                        searchedItem.Price = Double.Parse(price);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    else if (nodeChild.Name == "CustomerReviews")
                    {
                        foreach (XmlNode nodeCustomerReview in nodeChild.ChildNodes)
                        {
                            if (nodeCustomerReview.Name == "Review")
                            {
                                foreach (XmlNode nodeReview in nodeCustomerReview.ChildNodes)
                                {
                                    if (nodeReview.Name == "Content")
                                    {
                                        searchedItem.CustomerReview = nodeReview.InnerText;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                searchedItems.Add(searchedItem);
            }
        }
                    return searchedItems;
    }
```

Thank You for help!

Answer (score 0):

Providing a simple example of selecting nodes with Xpath, try this way

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        doc.Load(@"c:\XMLFile.xml");

        XmlNodeList elemPrice = doc.SelectNodes("/catalog/cd/price");

        for (int i = 0; i < elemPrice.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(elemPrice[i].Name);
            Console.WriteLine(elemPrice[i].InnerText);
        }
```

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<catalog>
  <cd country="USA">
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <price>10.90</price>
  </cd>
  <cd country="UK">
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <price>10.0</price>
  </cd>
  <cd country="USA">
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <price>9.90</price>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

Output
price
10.90
price
10.0
price
9.90